# If $W, V$ are algebraic and $W \subseteq V$, then $W$ is irreducible if and only if its closure $\overline W$ is irreducible. Isn't $W = \overline W$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

We defined the Zariski topology as the closed sets being exactly the algebraic sets of $K^n$, where $K$ is an algebraically closed field. If $W$ is algebraic, shouldn't it mean $W$ is closed? Then the lemma wouldn't be meaningful at all since $\overline W = W$. Am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that quasi-affine sets are allowed, too. That is, intersections of Zariski open sets with Zariski closed sets. For instance on a curve $C$ in $\Bbb{A}^2_k$, you could take $C\cap U$ where $U$ is the complement of a line $L$ through $C$, to get a quasi-affine set consisting of $C\setminus C\cap L$. That is, $C$ with a finite number of points removed.